# GeForce 9300M GS hdmi audio not working

Tags: nvidia, hdmi

my laptop seems to no longer support audio over hdmi after upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04. 
lspci output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Graphics Port (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G98 [GeForce 9300M GS] (rev a1)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
```

`sudo aplay -L` output

```
default
Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
sysdefault:CARD=Intel
HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
Front speakers
surround40:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
HDA Intel, ALC888 Digital
IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
HDA Intel, ALC888 Digital
Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
HDA Intel, ALC888 Digital
Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
HDA Intel, ALC888 Digital
Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=0
HDA Intel, ALC888 Analog
Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=Intel,DEV=1
HDA Intel, ALC888 Digital
Hardware device with all software conversions
```

`cat /proc/asound/cards` output

```
 0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                  HDA Intel at 0xfe200000 irq 47
```

NVIDIA Driver Version: 310.14

Thanks for help.

E

Answer (score 0):

HDMI audio is off by default, install grub2 customizer, under general tab change 'quiet splash' to 'quiet splash nvidia.audio=1'.